# Using Photos.app with dual displays

Tags: display, photos.app

I have a Mac with 2 screens.

Is there a way of persuading Photos.app to display an image full screen on one, whilst showing the Gallery, tools etc on the other?

Aperture.app used to do this, but I cannot figure out how to Photos.app do it, and my Google skills have failed me too.

Thanks for a definitive answer either way!

(In case it's useful, Big Sur 11.4; Photos 6.0 but this has been an issue since Catalina.)

Comment: I wish you luck but I don't think it's possible. Even the new Nikon Studio app has forgotten to include this - I went back to the older, no longer supported ViewNX-i to get it back [I also hung onto Aperture as long as I could] Everything these days seems to be built for laptops.

Comment: Thank you! It's a shame, and I do miss Aperture. It may be time to try LightRoom again, although I preferred Aperture first time round.

Comment: I'd say it depends what you shoot on - if it's one of the 'majors', a DSLR/mirrorless etc, I'd use the company's own app. I don't like what Lr does to my RAWs, they haven't managed to properly reverse-engineer Nikon's RAW 'decoding' properly, leaving everything flat & lack-lustre… more work in the long run, imho. [Back in my Aperture days I was just shooting on an iPhone, so there was no RAW to worry about]